# Sync iPad 2 (9.3.5) with MacBook Pro (Monterey)

Tags: mac, ipad, finder

I’ve decided to use my old iPad 2 as an e-reader. I have been trying to add pdf files to Books using the finder. Every time I do so, the status gets stuck on “waiting for items to copy.” Any ideas? The tablet shows up in finder and I can back it up, etc. the problem arises when I try to add pdf files to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer to my specific questions re Books app, but a workaround that gets almost the same result:

I have Comic Zeal on the iPad and I can drag-and-drop files from another finder window to that app and they transfer fine and are perfectly readable.